# solr "-" not working in some cases and works for some cases

Tags: java, solr

I am facing a problem where i have two strings "t-150" and "w-elksrc". After indexing i put following queries :-

Query1: `q=name:t-*&facet.query=t-&qt=autocomplete-identifier&hl=true&hl.fl=name&hl.ptc=true`

Query2: `q=name:w-*&facet.query=w-&qt=autocomplete-identifier&hl=true&hl.fl=name&hl.ptc=true`

Query1 us returning me "t-150" . However query 2 is returning me "" (blank). When i remove dash from query 2 and put space and character which means "w e" then i am getting result.

The field name has "text" type on indexing time i am using `ClassicTokenizerFactory`, `WordDelimiterFilterFactory`, `LowerCaseFilterFactory` and at query time `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`, `LowerCaseFilterFactory`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `ClassicTokenizerFactory` treats the stream in the following way -

> Words are split at hyphens, unless there is a number in the word, in which case the token is not split and the numbers and hyphen(s) are preserved.

So according to the documentation your input "t-150" will remain as `t-150` as it has a number. However the input "w-elkscr" will be split into two tokens i.e. `w` and `elkscr`.